# Memory management for TextView with a lot of text Android

Tags: android, performance, textview

I need to display a `TextView` with potentially a lot of text (meaning much more than the size of the screen's). Not surprisingly, this amount of text causes very unsmooth scrolling or potentially crashes the app.
I've tried myself to extend `TextView` so that it only displays the text which is on the screen and doesn't display the rest, but unfortunately my implementation is still a bit slow.

Does anyone know of any libraries which use memory management to make very large textviews feasible?

Comment: Consider using a WebView

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are WebViews good at displaying large amounts of text?

Comment: Yes they are. WebViews are meant to handle large amount of data. This should resolve your problem.